# How to implement notification mail in Jmeter?

Tags: smtp, jmeter, report, aggregate, performance-testing

How to configure the notification email in Jmeter script?, My Ideas is to implement the notification once test was start and end of the test.

In End of the test Aggregate report will send along with Notification mail, any one have idea about this?

[Please check this screen shot which i configure is correct or it need any modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc9w6.png)

Smtp sampler was executed but the i cannot get any email notification.please suggest me any modification is need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter provides [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) which you can use for sending the email notifications.

With regards to sending the report - I would suggest using [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) with 1 user and 1 loop for this. tearDown Thread Group will be executed after all other Thread Groups. Also make sure you have the following line added to *user.properties* file

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
```

JMeter doesn't store all the results in the real time, it flushes them into .jtl results file periodically in chunks so above setting will allow you to ensure that the results file is complete.

See [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) article for more information on configuring JMeter for sending emails.

Comment: Dmitri I checked the above website and i configure the email notification with Google server which it is mention in website but there are not mention the password for that server only they are mentioned username.

You have any idea for password for that google server?

Comment: It should be your account password

Comment: dmitry please find the screen shot in above question, i configured like which showed in the article, but i didn't get any email notification.